# How to anchor fork separation in forest trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, edge, anchor

In the process of creating a family tree using forest, I have used `forked edge` style in the main `for tree{}`. However **when the children node texts vary in length, the parent node's fork loses it's centering**. I tried `anchor=center`, `text centered`, `parent anchor=center` and none produced the desired result.

Here is the MWE:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        % styles
        man/.style = {fill=green},
        woman/.style = {fill=yellow},
        for tree={draw={black, thick},
            edge = {draw, thick},
            rounded corners,
            inner sep=5pt,
            s sep=15mm,
            l sep=10mm,
            anchor=center,
            forked edge,
            text centered
        },
        % tree starts here
        [Parent, man
            [Child1, man
                [Child1, man]
                [Child345123231, man]
                [Chiild11, man]
                [Child5677, man]
                [Child123122, woman]
            ]
            [Child2, man
                [Child256677, man]
                [Child2412345, man]
                [Child2312, man]
            ]
            [Child3232, man
                [Child4343, man]
            ]
            [Child4223231131, woman]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image]

Please help me avoid this by letting me know where I should add the necassary option. I'm sure this one has a simple solution (and many at that) but I'm not able to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `calign=child, calign child=[number]` syntax to align the items.

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        % styles
        man/.style = {fill=green},
        woman/.style = {fill=yellow},
        for tree={draw={black, thick},
            edge = {draw, thick},
            rounded corners,
            inner sep=5pt,
            s sep=15mm,
            l sep=10mm,
            anchor=center,
            forked edge,
            text centered
        },
        % tree starts here
        [Parent, man
            [Child1, calign=child,calign child=3, man
                [Child1, man]
                [Child345123231, man]
                [Chiild11, man]
                [Child5677, man]
                [Child123122, woman]
            ]
            [Child2, calign=child,calign child=2, man
                [Child256677, man]
                [Child2412345, man]
                [Child2312, man]
            ]
            [Child3232, man
                [Child4343, man]
            ]
            [Child4223231131, woman]
        ]
    \end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now even the docs make sense.